# Updating field issue

Tags: c#, .net, update

This is my Code, It modifies the inner text, pulls the correct inner text but doesn not save. Am I missing something?

```
        String queryString = "SELECT Comments__c FROM ts2__Application__c WHERE ts2__Job__c = '" + ssSearchesId + "' AND ts2__Candidate_Contact__c = '" + ssContactId + "'";
        SessionInfo sessionInfo = SessionInfoCache.Instance[ssSessionToken];
        QueryResult qr = sessionInfo.Binding.query(queryString);
        sObject[] sforceObj = qr.records;
        sforceObj[0].Any[0].InnerText = (ssComment + Environment.NewLine + sforceObj[0].Any[0].InnerText).Trim();
        sessionInfo.Binding.update(sforceObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your final line of code with

`SaveResult[] saveResults = sessionInfo.Binding.update(sforceObj);`

And validate you aren't having any errors within your saveResults array.

Fields available for this object are `Id` (string/id), `Success` (boolean), and `Errors`

[Documentation Here for SaveResult Object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_update_saveresult.htm)

Comment: Thank you, it gave me an error that I wasn't passing in ID